# how customize drupal 7 for multi user instance

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

When generating a new drupal site (multisite), I would like to define the default user profile as an admin user without acces to administration menu.

**How can I create this new user as an install profile with default login infos, keeping at the same time the admin user?**
 i found this [node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101902/create-a-user-via-the-installation-profile) ,but i can't understand ! how can I apply !?
Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://data.agaric.com/providing-default-user-installation-profile-drupal-7) lays out how to create roles and accounts in an install profile.

The core idea is to programmatically create a new role and user account in the profile .install file. For example (untested):

```
// Create a role for site content managers
$admin_role         = new stdClass();
$admin_role->name   = 'content manager';
$admin_role->weight = 2;
user_role_save($admin_role);

// Grant all admin permissions
user_role_grant_permissions($admin_role->rid, array_keys(module_invoke_all('permission')));

// Revoke the toolbar permissions
user_role_revoke_permissions($admin_role->rid, array(
  'access administration menu', // The admin_menu module toolbar
  'access toolbar', // The core toolbar
));

// Create a user with the content manager role
$new_user           = array();
$new_user['name']   = 'manager';
$new_user['mail']   = 'manager@example.com';
$new_user['roles']  = array($admin_role->rid => $admin_role->rid);
$new_user['pass']   = 'incredibly-secure-password-here';
$new_user['status'] = 1;

$account = user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $new_user);
```